# Add fix number/criteria to countif function

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A                      B                    C                    D
1                     Purchase Price        Sales Price      Purchase Price > Sales Price
2     Product A            50                    40        ={COUNTIF(B2:B6;">"&C2:C6)}
3     Product B            60                    65
4     Product C            80                    60
5     Product D            10                    20
6     Product E            50                    30
```

With the formular in cell D2 I detect the number of products where the Purchase Price is higher than the Sales Price. This formula works perfectly. Now, I want to change the formula in cell D2 so it counts the products where the *Purchase Price > Sales Price - 10* which in case of Product B would mean that the Sales Price is 65 - 10 = 55 and therefore needs to be counted from the formula in cell D2.

Do you know how I can add this non-tolerance range of 10 to my formula in cell D2?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B6>C2:C6-10))
```

[image]